# Suposta pobreza vocabular para riso e sorriso

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, vocabulário, termos-em-inglês, neologismos

Ao escrever com as línguas portuguesa e inglesa, notei que existe dificuldade na primeira para exprimir as expressões faciais relacionadas a alegria, deleite: 'sorrir' e 'rir'.
Com uma busca no site ['Sinônimos'](https://www.sinonimos.com.br/) é possível encontrar para a busca de 'sorrir':

> **Sorrir:**
>
> Fazer um sorriso: rir

Enquanto que para 'rir', temos:

> **Rir:**
>
> Sorrir: sorrir, gargalhar, alegrar-se, aprazer-se, gargalhadear, desfrutar.

Percebe-se que o terceiro, quarto, e sexto sinônimos não referenciam expressões faciais; e que o segundo comunica a mesma ação que o quinto. Portanto, existem no total três palavras.

Na língua inglesa, entretanto, existe abundância de verbos e substantivos para os diferentes tipos de sorrisos e risadas (ironicamente, sendo que as línguas germânicas são ditas mais robóticas que as românicas): grin, smug, giggle, chortle, chuckle, snicker, e outros mais obscuros.

A pergunta é: existe uma forma de resolver isso? Há vocábulos dos quais não tenho conhecimento, expressões linguísticas de outros idiomas (inglês, latim) que podem ser usadas (com ou sem problemas) no português? E seria válido que fossem formulados novos termos para solucionar essa deficiência, e.g. to chuckle -> resrir: res (latim, restringere, impedir) + rir?

Comment: Que é que estás a pedir aqui? Traduções para cada um dos vocábulos que dás? Que "existe forma de resolver isso" é claro que há: os tradutores fazem-no todos os dias (de forma mais ou menos satisfatória).

Comment: Talvez a pergunta esteja após “A pergunta é:”, não sei, talvez a humanidade nunca saiba responder. E não, os tradutores não exibem nada satisfatório porque superficialmente não há tradução satisfatória.

Comment: A  única forma que vejo de responder a "existe uma forma de resolver isso" é explicando como traduzir cada um desses termos (por exemplo, com traduções duplas `ele A e B`, diminutivos/aumentativos/advérbios de modo). Se não é essa a pergunta, então não é claro qual é e voto para fechar com essa razão.

Comment: @WilliamLio lembre-se que o título remete a uma questão, então tente ser mais objetivo no título e sobre o que deseja. Por exemplo: 'Como expressar a variação de risos em inglês para português em uma palavra?', 'Qual palavra utilizar para de 'x' (inglês) para português', dentro do conteúdo pode ser explicar os passos que você fez (ex: pesquisei em dicionários) e o que deseja alcançar reforçando a dúvida que foi colocada no título com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permita-me primeiro chamar a atenção ao fato de que em geral não é recomendável fazer julgamentos de valor de línguas - não porque seja politicamente incorreto, mas porque raramente esses julgamentos terão bom embasamento. Também melhor evitados, na minha opinião, são qualificativos vagos e emocionalmente carregados como "robótico".

Mas, sim: até onde sei, e também de acordo com os dicionários que chequei, parece haver menos palavras no português que no inglês para descrever tipos diferentes de riso e sorriso. Há expressões coloquiais, como `rachar o bico` (rir muito) e palavras menos usadas, como [cachinar](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/cachinar/), mas quase sempre se usa *rir*, *sorrir* ou *gargalhar*.

Isso não implica perda de expressividade. A "forma de resolver" a falta de palavras específicas, como sempre, é o uso de expressões e frases, i.e., é pelo uso de advérbios e adjetivos: *sorriso matreiro*, *risada forçada*, etc. *To giggle*, por exemplo, pode ser traduzido como "*dar risadinhas*"; *to snicker*, "dar um riso reprimido/entredentes"; *to grin*, "*dar um sorriso largo/amplo/malicioso/...*" conforme o contexto, etc.

A introdução de neologismos sempre é uma possibilidade, mas uma que deve ser tratada com muita cautela e que é indicada em trabalhos de tradução apenas em casos específicos (e.g., em trabalhos técnicos, onde um termo preciso é necessário e pode realmente não existir ainda).

Comment: Boa resposta. De fato que “robótico” para línguas germânicas não passa de um preconceito popular. Entretanto, devo discordar dos julgamentos de valor, por parecer confirmado por nós que a língua portuguesa peca nesse aspecto léxico, e por ser de consenso geral que as línguas românicas soam mais belas/humanas/emocionais, justificando-se pela ortografia, e palavras terminadas usualmente em vogais ou consoantes fracas. Julgar uma língua quando clara e evidente estiver a crítica, melhor permite seu manejo e consequente evolução.

Comment: @WilliamLio, Também não vejo problema em, com embasamento, avaliar uma língua (por exemplo, o [Pirahã](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3_language#Numerals_and_grammatical_number) deve ser uma língua complicada para fazer contabilidade, dado que, aparentemente, não tem numerais :)). Minha observação se deve apenas a uma possível interpretação negativa de sua pergunta (que creio notar na reação a ela) que, por sua vez, se justifica pela frequente superficialidade destes julgamentos e, especialmente, pela séria problemática de preconceitos envolvida.